# AWS select the CloudFormer template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to create a CloudFormation YAML template from the existing resources and faces some issues. I read in the blogs that we can have the CloudFormaer template available like below:

[image]

However, I don't see this coming when creating the stack from the AWS dashboard.

[image]

Apparently, it supposes to be in the tools section which they deleted the template and created a new way for the template. Do I miss anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFormer is no longer available in the console's sample templates:

["The beta for the CloudFormer template creation tool has ended."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html)

["We are not planning to enhance CloudFormer in its current form. We recommend using https://former2.com/, an opensource tool contributed by Ian McKay"](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/439#issuecomment-611676438)

https://github.com/iann0036/former2#security

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just wasting time there.